# edit dimension of array vba

Tags: arrays, vba, dimensions

I have an array like this

```
dim arr(1 to 5) as string

arr(1)="a"
arr(3)="b"
arr(5) = "c"
```

(arr(2),arr(4) are empty).

How can I redim this arr(1to5) to exclude empty values and save also values "a","b","c" (I want the output like `arr(1to3), arr(1)="a", arr(2)="b", arr(3)="c"`)?
In general I do not know how many of them will be empty, so I need some general code for this (not for this specific example).

I was thinking about new temporary array to save all nonempty values and then redim arr(1to5).

Maybe it is a better (quick) way to do it?

```
I wrote sth similar:
Sub test()
Dim myArray() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim y As Long


ReDim Preserve myArray(3)
myArray(1) = "a"
myArray(3) = "c"

Dim myArray2() As String
y = 1
For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)

If myArray(i) <> "" Then

ReDim Preserve myArray2(y)
myArray2(y) = myArray(i)
y = y + 1

End If
Next i

ReDim myArray(UBound(myArray2))
myArray = myArray2

End Sub
```

However I would like to avoid creating new array.

Comment: create a new array of the same size.  Loop the first array and insert the values when not empty into the new array keeping track of the last spot with value in the new array, then redim preserve the new array to only the size that has values.

Comment: Also worth asking if maybe there is a design issue with the application. Can you let us know the bigger picture?

Comment: Consider to use a collection or dictionay

Comment: @EmiliaRajchel Posted a solution via negative filtering of the original array elements.

Comment: @T.M. Sorry, I did not know that I have to mark this. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternative via `Filter()` function**

> *"However I would like to avoid creating new array."*

A negative filtering allows a basically simple alternative, however you have to

- declare your array dynamically (i.e. without preset number of elements) to allow a rebuild overwriting the original array,
- execute a double replacement over the joined array elements to allow insertion of a unique character that can be filtered out.

```
Sub testFilter()
    Dim arr() As String                                     
    ReDim arr(1 To 5)
    arr(1) = "a"
    arr(3) = "b"
    arr(5) = "c"
    'Debug.Print Join(arr, ",")                             ' ~~> a,,b,,c     

    'rearrange arr via RemoveEmpty()
    arr = RemoveEmpty(arr)                                  ' >>  function RemoveEmpty()
    Debug.Print Join(arr, ",")                              ' ~~> a,b,c

End Sub
```

**Help function RemoveEmpty()**

Adding an unused *unique* character, e.g. `$`, to the empty elements plus eventual negative filtering allows to remove these marked elements.

*Note* that the double replacement is necessary to allow to mark consecutive *empty* elements by the `$` mark, as VBA would skip additional characters here.

```
Function RemoveEmpty(arr)
    Dim tmp
    tmp = Replace(Replace(Join(arr, "|"), "||", "|$|"), "||", "|$|")
    RemoveEmpty = Filter(Split(tmp, "|"), "$", False)
End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

create a new array of the same size. Loop the first array and insert the values when not empty into the new array keeping track of the last spot with value in the new array, then redim preserve the new array to only the size that has values.

```
Sub kjlkj()
    Dim arr(1 To 5) As String
    
    arr(1) = "a"
    arr(3) = "b"
    arr(5) = "c"
    
    Dim newArr() As String
    ReDim newArr(1 To UBound(arr))
    
    Dim j As Long
    j = LBound(newArr)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) <> "" Then
            newArr(j) = arr(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    ReDim Preserve newArr(LBound(newArr) To j - 1)

    'do what you want with the new array.
    
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution, but probably I would prefer a Collection or Dictionary. BTW: Nice subroutine name - I use it also all the time ;-)

Comment: I think I use `asdfasdf` or something similar haha.

Comment: Helpful, especially as redimming after loop. - fyi posted a simple alternative via VBA's `Filter()` function.